# How do I tell bitbucket to show a certain changeset by default?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I´ve have configured Mercurial together with SourceTree and Bitbucket. I´m able to see all the files in Bitbucket as long as i´m just adding files to the SourceTree repository. However, if i´m changing to another version (using right click and "Update To" in SourceTree), the updates are not pushed to Bitbucket. When I press the Push button in SourceTree, it says "No changes to push". (Even though the version is changed locally on my computer).

Thankful for any help!

[Cannot push updates to BitBucket from SourceTre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4rY9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

That's to be expected. When using mercurial, a push by default pushes *all public and draft revisions* in *all branches*. Thus locally updating your checked-out working copy will not magically add anything new to push.

As it's a distributed VCS, a push will never change the working dir state of any other repository. Concerning repository browsers and web management systems like bitbucket a similar argument has to be made (as they usually do not have any working dir at all, so-called 'bare repositories'). By default they most likely show the newest changeset or newest changeset to default branch. It can be argued that the commit bookmarked with '@' might make sense as well. However they might offer in their UI to show by default a particular revision or branch,  and that includes bitbucket.

Comment: I see. So how should I update the Bitbucket repository in that case?

Comment: Are you sure bitbucket does not have the revisions you look for already?

Comment: I can see all my commits in Bitbucket. But, if I go to "Source", the version is not corresponding to the one I have locally on my computer.

Comment: Are all your commits there when you select 'commits' in the bitbucket interface? How does that compare to the local output of `hg log -G`?

Comment: Yes. The "hg log -G" command in SourceTree shows the same commits as the Bitbucket interface.

Comment: Then what's the problem? You have the same commits everywhere and you can access every commit both locally as well as on bitbucket.

Comment: I can just see the commits in Bitbucket. I can´t access the version I have locally on my computer.

Comment: It's really not clear to me in what your problem is. You should join some online help, best concerning sourcetree itself. Something here in what you write doesn't add up: both, local and bitbucket history are identical. Is your issue using bitbucket interface, showing a specific revision there? Is your problem that you do not know how to use the funky GUI in order to update locally to whatever revision you choose? Or did you not commit and wonder about where the uncommitted changes are? Something else? I don't see how the linked screenshot helps to describe your problem at all.

Comment: I suggest alternatively or additionally to revise your question a lot to illustrate and desribe the problem. That nothing can be pushed doesn't seem to be an issue as the history is identical (unless you forgot to commit some pending changes). Also try to achieve the goal without using sourcetree and using hg command line directly.

Comment: You are making it too complicated.I want to switch between diffrent versions. But Bitbucket is not reflecting my local system. How can I fix so Bitbucket is showing the same version as my local computer?

Comment: Then you should write / ask just that. Simple answer: you can't. Bitbucket shows the newest commit by default, that's it. Maybe you can use the special @ bookmark to trick it into showing that particular revision - but I doubt it. Also how could bitbucket know or do? Consider a repo with two commiters. One checks-out rev1, the other rev2. What should bitbucket do then? Bitbucket has no checked-out revision, it is just a web viewer for the repo history. If there is anywhere something which can be done, it's found in the bitbucket UI.

Comment: Simple answer: This is super easy with Github and Github desktop. Problem solved.